# Problems while making scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

Hello everyone,
               I am trying to show the track of a tropical cyclone by using a scatter plot over a spatial plot containing sst. Now while plotting the track the scatter doesn't seem to plot all the plots, mostly it is seen over land its not plotting the points. I am not able to make out where I am doing wrong in my code, if anyone can help in this regard it will be much appreciated. I am posting part of my code along with the lat long values and the plot which I have generated.I am giving the lat long data as text as below:

```
Lat Lon grade
10.4 87 D
10.9 86.3 D
10.9 86.3 CS
11.1 86.1 CS
11.4 86 CS
11.5 86 SCS
12 86 VSCS
12.5 86.1 VSCS
13.2 86.3 ESCS
13.4 86.2 SuCS
14   86.3 SuCS
14.9 86.5 SuCS
15.6 86.7 SuCS
16.5 86.9 ESCS
17.4 87 ESCS
18.4 87.2 ESCS
19.1 87.5 ESCS
20.6 88 ESCS
21.9 88.4 VSCS
23.3 89 SCS
24.2 89.3 CS
25 89.6 DD
25.4 89.6 D



cs=map.contourf(x,y,plt_data,clevels,cmap=plt.cm.jet)#,clevels,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    map.colorbar(cs)

df = pd.read_excel('E:/bst_trc.xls',sheet_name='Sheet6')
colors = {'SuCS': 'red', 'ESCS': 'blue', 'SCS': 'green', 'D': 'black', 'VSCS': 'orange', 'DD':'cyan', 
              'CS': 'magenta'}

df['x'], df['y'] = map(list(df['Lon']), list(df['Lat']))
for grade in list(df['grade'].unique()):
ax.scatter(df[df['grade'] == grade]['x'],
           df[df['grade'] == grade]['y'],
           s = 50,
           label = grade,
           facecolors = colors[grade])

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'k-', lw = 1.5)
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
      fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=7)
#plt.savefig('E:/Super_cyclone/Amphan/sst_bfr.tif', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi can you share your data in a format that allows us to play with it?

Comment: @warped like which data you want...the sst data or the lat long values data.

Comment: the bit that isn't working ;)

Comment: ok sure.... am posting the lat long excel data.

Comment: You data file only has 4, maybe 5 points over land.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @jmh yes...am giving you the google drive link from where you can download the excel file....

Comment: @warped https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_G9XyaK9oTGEa3G817b9I6aMhu11LPqy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, but this requires you to give access. Can you simply provide a subset of your data as text in your post, s.t. everybody who wants to help you can help you?

Comment: @warped ya sure

Comment: @warped please check the edited post

Comment: What happens when you do not plot the underlying image? Are all datapoints there?

Answer (score 0):

```
grade_unique = df['grade'].unique()
grade_unique

colormap = {a:b/len(grade_unique) for b,a in enumerate(grade_unique)}

df['color'] = df['grade'].replace(colormap)

plt.plot(df['Lon'], df['Lat'], c='k')
plt.scatter(df['Lon'], df['Lat'], c=df['color'], cmap='magma')

plt.hlines(y=25,xmin=0,xmax=100, linestyles='dashed')

plt.ylim(5,30)
plt.xlim(75,95)
```

[image]

Plotting the data you supplied gives this.
I rescaled to get all data points onto the plot, and drew a line at your upper ylimit. So you are missing one datapoint because of scaling.

Comment: @warpedI am still having the same problem

Comment: @DebashisPaul the data that you put into your post can be plotted like this, and there are no missing datapoints. Did you try to plot using my code?

Comment: Yes i tried, everything is ok but as soon as the track falls over the land their aint any scatter points...but the black line is their without any scatter points...i am not getting why is it so...if possible can u try with some random netcdf data and try to plot the sactter points over the basemap..then you may know